# Hide phone numbers above 9 digits in <p> tags and exclude <span> tags inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

Hi I went through many answers on this but couldn't find a similar one which worked. Kindly help with this.
I have a script which hides mobile number inside `<p></p>` tag, the present script hides any numbers added. We want this to be like it should hide numbers which are above 9 digits only. And also if it has
`<span></span>` tag it should not hide the mobile number. Can we achieve this please.

We want it like this:

```
<p>Hide 1234567890<span>Show 0987654321</span></p>
```

Output will be: 'Hide *** Show 0987654321'

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hidenumber').find('p').text(function(i,txt) {
    return txt.replace(/[1-9]+/,'***');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain better the <span></span>? is this inside the <p>? Or maybe also add a html example of the rendered code.

Comment: Its actually going inside: <p>Contact 1234567890</p> and the output is like Contact ***

Comment: We want it '<p>Contact 1234567890 <span>or 0987654321</span></p>' the output will be like this: Contact *** 0987654321

Comment: Btc, please add that information to the question, where it's visible to those viewing questions and can be formatted for readability. Comments are temporary (by design), and prone to deletion.

Comment: You gave examples where the number contains `0`- but `[1-9]` does not include 0.

Comment: _"which are above 9 digits only"_ - replace the quantifier `+`, which means one or more, with `{9,}` (nine or more) then.

Comment: _"And also if it has <span></span> tag it should not hide the mobile number."_ - are there any cases where there is _only_ a mobile number, and it does not have a landline number in front of it? Because without the `g` modifier, your current statement would replace the _first_ match it finds only anyway, so in that case you would not have to do anything else.

Comment: Hi mostly it would only be Mobile number no telephone number

Comment: "*mostly it would only be Mobile number no telephone number*" - I don't understand, a mobile number *is* a telephone number; also "mostly" doesn't mean "always."

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#hidenumber').find('p').text(function (i, txt) {
            // if <p> does not contain <span>
            if ($(this).find('span').length == 0) {
                return txt.replace(/\d{9,}/g, '***');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer tried it but doesn't work we want it like this: '<p>Hide 1234567890<span>Show 0987654321</span></p>' . Output will be: 'Hide *** Show 0987654321'.

Comment: "*...we want it like this:...*" - then add that to the question, at least give people a fair chance of answering the question.

Comment: I have added this up on question. sorry if missed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Using the **Node.TEXT_NODE** will exclude text/numbers in the other elements such as span.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Hide span numbers</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hidenumber").contents().each(function() {
            if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                $(this).replaceWith(this.nodeValue.replace(/\b\d{10,}\b/g, '***'));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="hidenumber">
Hide 1234567890 <span>Show 0987654321</span><br>
Hide: 1234567890234 <span>Show 0987654321</span><br>
Show: 123456789 <span>Show: 0987654321</span><br>
Show: 1234567 <span>Show: 0987654321</span><br>
Hide: 1234567899 <span>Show: 123451234512345</span><br>
Hide: 1234567899 Hide: 123451234512345
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Adam (APB Reports)